# Replacing background worker with task/async/await?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, task

I send a 7 byte TX command I am to receive a 7 byte RX response.

If possible, I'd like to chain the receive bytes task to send bytes task as this only seems logical.

I am aware that background workers are outdated and would like to modernize the code by utilizing the [Task-Parallel-Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Can someone elucidate how to replace the backgroundWorker_DoWork event handler with an async task for the context described?

Comment: `BackgroundWorker` runs on a dedicated background thread, whereas `Task`s usually don't. Would this be acceptable?

Comment: You can switch from Synchronous To Asynchronous method with Network Stream : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.networkstream?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 1):

If you are always first sending bytes, and then receiving bytes, you could use something like this:

```
public static class NetworkStreamExtensions
{
    public static async Task<byte[]> SendReceiveBytes(this NetworkStream self, byte[] toSend, int bytesToReceive, CancellationToken cancel)
    {
        await self.WriteAsync(toSend, 0, toSend.Length, cancel);
        var receiveBuffer = new byte[bytesToReceive];
        var receivedBytes = await self.ReadAsync(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length, cancel);

        if (receivedBytes != receiveBuffer.Length)
        {
            // Handle incorrect number of received bytes, 
        }

        return receiveBuffer;
    }
}
```

As this is using async/await it will use the current synchronization context to run the code. I.e. If called on the main thread, it will send and receive on the main thread. It will however permit other code to run between Writing and reading, since async methods does not block execution.